# Train bvlc_reference_caffenet with input data scaled to [0,1]

Tags: caffe

I followed the [Caffe ImageNet Tutorial](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/imagenet.html) and could successfully train the bvlc_reference_caffenet. Now I would like to scale the input data from [0,255] to [0,1] (since I later have to run this CNN on hardware with limited fixed/floating point accuracy) like in the [Caffe LeNet MNIST Tutorial](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/mnist.html) where it is done by adding a `scale` parameter to the `data` layer:

```
layer {
  name: "mnist"
  type: "Data"
  transform_param {
    scale: 0.00390625
  }
  data_param {
    source: "mnist_train_lmdb"
    backend: LMDB
    batch_size: 64
  }
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
}
```

Due to this I added this scale parameter also to the bvlc_reference_caffenet and also divide the mean parameter which will be subtracted from each channel by 255:

```
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  transform_param {
     crop_size: 227
     scale: 0.00390625
     mean_value: 0.40784313
     mean_value: 0.45882352
     mean_value: 0.48235294
     mirror: true
  }
  data_param {
    source: "examples/imagenet/ilsvrc12_train_lmdb"
    batch_size: 32
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  transform_param {
    crop_size: 227
    scale: 0.00390625
    mean_value: 0.40784313
    mean_value: 0.45882352
    mean_value: 0.48235294
    mirror: false
  }
  data_param {
    source: "examples/imagenet/ilsvrc12_val_lmdb"
    batch_size: 32
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
```

When I train the net now the accuracy will always be lower than chance. What other parameters do I have to adopt to train the net with [0,1] images instead of [0,255] images?

Answer (score 3):

Caffe first subtracts the mean and then scales the result. You should retain your original `0...255` mean values.
Reference:

```
if (has_mean_file) {
          transformed_data[top_index] =
            (datum_element - mean[data_index]) * scale;
}
```

([data_transformer.cpp](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/data_transformer.cpp))